# getting ajax response when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im creating a star rating system and it works but need to have the current amount of votes to be displayed when the page loads and im having issues implementing this with the code i have to work with due to the plugin source code and its ajax as its not a language im very familiar with.

It puts the current votes in the element i want it to when a the click handler is activated by selecting a rating but really not sure if i need to add to the current function or create a new one and if so how do i get it not to conflict with the current one.

thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php require 'core/init.php'; ?>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="randomtest" class="star"></div></td>
                <td id="cvotes"></td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="star/assets/js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $.fn.raty.defaults.path = 'star/assets/img';
        $('.star').raty({

            half      : true,
            number    : 5,
            score     : 3,

            click: function(score, evt) {
            /*implement this for only click once 
             * $(this).find('img').unbind('click');
             */

            var pid=$(this).prop('id');

                $.ajax({
                url: 'rate.php',
                data: { score: score, pid:pid },
                type: 'POST',

                success: function (data) {
                    $('#cvotes').empty().append(data + ' Votes.'); // this needs to be done on page load too!
                },
                error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                    $('#cvotes').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
                }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware that since you are using #cvotes as a unique element on the page every result will appear on this single element no matter how many .star elements you have on page.

for the rating data to be loaded at the right time you have to do ajax get request after you initiate your raty plugin.

you should really do it inside the plugin code, but doing it on pageready like this should also work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    function onRateResultsSuccess(data) {
        $('#cvotes').empty().append(data + ' Votes.'); 
    }

    function onRateResultsError(data) {
        $('#cvotes').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
    }

    $.fn.raty.defaults.path = 'star/assets/img';
    $('.star').raty({

        half      : true,
        number    : 5,
        score     : 3,

        click: function(score, evt) {
        /*implement this for only click once 
         * $(this).find('img').unbind('click');
         */

        var pid=$(this).prop('id');

            $.ajax({
            url: 'rate.php',
            data: { score: score, pid:pid },
            type: 'POST',

            success: onRateResultsSuccess,
            error: onRateResultsError
            });
        }
    });

    // this should really be inside the raty plugin init as well as the click handler

    // for every .star element
    $('.star').each(function () {

            var pid=$(this).prop('id');

            // use http get
            $.get('rate.php', { pid:pid } ,onRateResultsSuccess).fail(onRateResultsError);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i just switch this code in and it didnt work but il go through it and get an idea of what your ding fully after ready ur answer. cheers

Comment: Well... You know, its not like i could have tested it, 
I do not have raty plugin or your rate.php,
make sure your rate.php responds to get request, 
you can just type the url in your browser to check. ie http://yourhostname/rate.php?pid=randomtest

Comment: I know and what you did is much appreciated, I ran the test and it echo's the current votes amount? (ps I just made a separate php file to run this small task independently of the updating the database file and still no joy)

Comment: I had one too many } 
try copy this instead
    $('.star').each(function () {

            var pid=$(this).prop('id');

            // use http get
            $.get('rate.php', { pid:pid } ,onRateResultsSuccess).fail(onRateResultsError);
    });

Comment: sorted it there was just an extra curly brace!! thanks again I'll mark this as right but edit the extra curly brace out of it at the bottom in case anyone else tries using this. :)

Comment: yeah, figured it out myself :)